# Prove by double inclusion $(A \Delta B) - C = (A - C) \Delta (B - C)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

$\subseteq$ Let A, B, C be sets.
Must first prove that:
$$
(A \Delta B) - C \subseteq (A - C) \Delta (B - C)
$$

Let $x \in (A \Delta B) - C$. Note:

$$
(A \Delta B) = (B - A) \cup (A - B)
$$

Therefore, $x \in ((B - A) \cup (A - B)) - C$.

If $x \in A$, then $x \notin B$. If $x \in B$, then $x \notin A$.

I'm a bit confused as to how to continue. I know that when subtracting C, you are left with the x's that are not in C and that are not shared by A and B. However, I am confused as to how to put that into notation. Should I use separate x and y?

Also, how would I go about proving that the right side of the equation is a subset of the left side as to prove by double inclusion?

Answer (score 1):

Since $x \in ((B-A)\cup (A-B))-C$ we have $x \in (B-A)-C$ or $x \in (A-B)-C$. Hence $x \in B, x \notin A, x \notin C$ or $x \in A, x \notin B, x \notin C$. So $x \in B-C, x\notin A-C$ or $x \in A-C, x\notin B-C$. Which implies that $x \in (B-C)-(A-C)$ or $x \in (A-C)-(B-C)$. And we have $x \in ((B-C)-(A-C))\cup ((A-C)-(B-C))=(A-C)\Delta(B-C)$.

For the other inclusion suppose $x \in (A-C)\Delta(B-C)=((B-C)-(A-C))\cup ((A-C)-(B-C))$. Then $x \in (B-C)-(A-C)$ or $x \in (A-C)-(B-C)$. Suppose $x \in (B-C)-(A-C)$. Then $x \in B, x \notin C, x \notin A-C$. Since $x \notin C$ and $x \notin A-C$ we have that $x \notin A$. So $x \in B-A$ and $x \notin C$. Then $x \in (B-A)-C$. If $x \in (A-C)-(B-C)$ show by a similar reasoning that $x \in (A-B)-C$. So $x \in ((B-A)-C) \cup (((A-B)-C)=(B-A) \cup (A-B))-C $ which by definition is $A\Delta B-C$.

Answer (score 0):

In fact
\begin{eqnarray}
(A - C) \Delta (B - C)&=&(A\cap C^c)\Delta(B\cap C^c)\\
&=&[(A\cap C^c)\cap(B\cap C^c)^c]\cup [(B\cap C^c)\cap(A\cap C^c)^c]\\
&=&[(A\cap C^c)\cap(B^c\cup C)]\cup [(B\cap C^c)\cap(A^c\cup C)]\\
&=&[A\cap C^c\cap B^c]\cup[B\cap C^c \cap A^c]\\
&=&[A\cap B^c]\cup[B\cap A^c]\cap C^c \\
&=&(A\Delta B)-C.
\end{eqnarray}